# Unable to receive email from Yahoo.com at my domain name

Tags: email, smtp, pop3

I have setup a custom domain (say mydomain) and a mail server for the domain name. Its a plain smtp/pop server (apache james). I am able to send messages to yahoo/gmail/ .... etc. however im unable to receive mails incoming to mydomain from yahoo. All yahoo messages get bounced back.

I don't know what can be wrong. I have not configured SPF and DKIM as I doubt that is mandatory. Im able to receive email from Gmail though.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Tobias Have added the question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/645456/unable-to-receive-email-from-yahoo-com-at-my-domain-name)